# Java class level type inference

Tags: java, generics

I know the code below doesn't compile, and yes I might be crazy.  What I'm trying to do is slip an implementation (B below) of a abstract class (A) as the super class of class (C) that also extends the abstract class.  I'd also like to defer method override to the super class.  Something like...

```
abstract class A {
  abstract Object get();
  abstract Object do();
  Object action();
}

class B extends A {
  B(B obj) {
      super(obj.getName()...)
   }
  Object get() { ... }
  Object do() { ... }
}

C<T> extends <T extends A> {
   C(<T extends A> obj) {
      super(obj)
   }

   Object do() { ... }

   Object whatever() {
      return action();
   }
}
```

Where...

```
C aC = new aC(new B());
aC.get() -> B.get()
aC.do() -> C.do()
aC.action() -> A.action()
```

Comment: No, you cannot dynamically define your class structure like that in Java. If you define an interface, you could use composition to accomplish this, together with a dynamic proxy. But that relies on reflection, which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Yep, I considered this.  That's a bit involved, especially since generics is right there.  I'll see if anything like this is upcoming.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the delegate pattern.

```
class C extends A {

   private final A delegate;

   C(A obj) {
      this.delegate = obj;
   }

   Object get() { return delegate.get() }

   Object whatever() {
      return action();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I ended up doing.  Thanks.